# Location of Git Executable for Jenkins on Windows

Tags: windows, git, jenkins

Which is the correct installation directory for Jenkins to use?  Here are the options I have tried and the results I have seen.

- C:\Git\bin\git.exe

[image]

- C:\Git\cmd\git

  same as above
- C:\Git\cmd\gitk.cmd

[image]

If I continue and ask the job to build here is the console output.

Started by an SCM change
Building in workspace C:\Jenkins\workspace\git_test
Checkout:git_test / C:\Jenkins\workspace\git_test - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@12f2468
Using strategy: Default
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository ssh:///jenkins@xxxx.yyyyyyyyy.com:test.git
git --version
Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
Fetching upstream changes from origin
Seen 0 remote branches
No candidate revisions
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE

Since they all result in one error or another its not clear which one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with git not being found but that `putty` has not yet been told that it can trust the ssh-key presented by the repository sshd server.

Run a manual git command first on the Jenkins server, so you can say yes to accept the host key, and then try again.